# Should associated floating IPs be configured/visible on VM?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

perhaps anybody here inside can assist me with a problem (or question) with floating IPs. I am creating a floating IP by allocating one from a defined pool and associate it to a running VM within my project. That works fine.

What I expected is that this floating IP is being configured in the VM so that I can see it inside the VM with a command like `ifconfig -a`, but I can't. The floating IP is not visible. My question is now: Does this "floating IP" mechanism works as expected? Is this IP only visible to some "virtual network stack" or should I see it configured on my VM. If I should see it on the VM: Do I have to configure anything there to make it "visible", i.e. do I have to configure an entry in `/etc/netplan/netcfg.yaml`? I'm running Ubuntu in the VM.

Thanks in advance for any hint!
Joachim.

Answer (score 0):

The floating IP-address is neither configured in the compute instance nor visible there.

A floating IP-address exists only as a mapping to the virtual network port created by OpenStack. It is a form of destination network address translation (NAT) or conceptually similar to port-forwarding all ports to a guest.
That is why floating IP-addresses can be added, removed and even allocated to different VM without any (re-) configuration on the guests.

If you don't get a response on the floating IP-address - check the security groups assigned to the compute instance.